# Question about nonempty assumption for left inverse iff injective and right inverse iff surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The following is a theorem from *Elements of Set Theory* by Enderton:

> Assume that $F:A\to B$ and that $A$ is nonempty. Then the following
> hold:
>
> (a) There exists a function $G:B\to A$ such that $G\circ F$ is the
> identity function $I_A$ on $A$ iff $F$ is one-to-one.
>
> (b) There exists a function $H:B\to A$ such that $F\circ H$ is the
> identity function $I_B$ on $B$ iff $F$ maps $A$ onto $B$.

I know that the nonempty assumption is used for the $\impliedby$ direction of (a). But I don't think it is used for any other part. Is this true? Did Enderton simply feel that it wasn't worth splitting up the theorem just for this reason?

Comment: If $A$ is nonempty there are no functions $B\to A$ at all.

Comment: @ElliotG Do you mean if $A$ is empty?

Comment: yes sorry $\hspace{1cm}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The problem is that *every* function $F : \varnothing \to B$ is injective, but if $B$ is inhabited then there are no functions $G : B \to \varnothing$ to speak of, so $F$ has no left inverse.

Crucially, when you construct a left inverse $G$ for an injection $F : A \to B$, you need to have (at least one) element $a^{\star} \in A$ to be the value of those elements of $B$ that are not in the image of $A$. Typically we fix one such $a^{\star} \in A$ and define $G(b) = a^{\star}$ for each $b \not\in \mathrm{im}(f)$. If $A$ is empty and $B$ is inhabited, then there is no $a^{\star} \in A$ that can serve this purpose.

However, this doesn't cause a problem for surjections: if a function $F : \varnothing \to B$ is surjective, then we must have $B=\varnothing$, and then $F$ is the (unique) function $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, so is its own right (and left) inverse.